# Script de redirecionamento de URL por país

Tags: javascript, redirecionamento, blog

Gostaria de saber se existe algum script como este por exemplo:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    / / Javascript URL redirection
    window.location.replace("Site de destino");
</script>
```

Porém que tivesse a função de redirecionar apenas usuários do país X dentro do blog para um site externo "site de destino"

Comment: só se você requisitar a localização do navegador ou se basear na cultura utilizada...

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo dar uma olhada no [GeoPlugin](https://www.geoplugin.com/), funciona por API e é facílimo de usar. Pegando o país de origem, um simples `redirect` do JavaScript deve resolver seu problema. Algo como:

```js
if(geoplugin_countryCode()) === "CN")
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

```html
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
```